# C# replace strings in array with LINQ

Tags: c#, regex, linq, replace

I have an string array of size 10:

> [0] = "1,0000000"
>   [1] = "479,00000"
>   ....
>       [9] = "145,0".

I want to remove the trailing ",00000" of the first 9 elements with regex and linq. Please help.

Comment: loop through the array and replace each element and do replacement like, `Regex.Replace(string, ",0+$", "")` add `*` instead of `+` if necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically I would do this like that :

```
var yourArray = new string[10];
var yourResult = yourArray.Take(9).Select(s => s.Split(',')[0]).ToArray();
```

But you can replace the Select method content with a Regex call if you wish.

Comment: Cool solution, using the `split`

Comment: My answer is very basic, but so is his question.

Comment: There will be no such cases. I did it in a lil bit different way with .Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, ",0+$", "")).ToArray(). Anyway...good to know. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

Use a for-loop and string methods like `IndexOf` and `Substring`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Math.Min(array.Length, 9); i++)
{
    int commaIndex = array[i].IndexOf(",");
    if(commaIndex >= 0) array[i] = array[i].Substring(0, commaIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try

```
data.forEach(x => x.replace("ABC", "'"));
```